# Structure Theorem For PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

So, I'm a biologist at KCL, but I quite like mathematics and so am going through a book of exercises in algebra. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem in trying to answer some of the questions. I've been told that here might be a nice place to ask and so I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me (my mathematician friends also tend to be strict about notation, so apologies if it's not right). The questions lead you to showing if you have a principal ideal domain and a finitely generated module over it, then that module must be the distinct sum of a free module and its torsion. I can get to this point. However, it then asks if this free module is unique and why this may be false if it's not over a principal ideal domain. Here is where I get stuck.

Attempt at solution: I don't fully understand what it means by unique. I tried to generate some modules to see if I could see what was happening, but I think I'm falling down at understanding how to use the torsion. I tried things like the integers, but ended up with no torsion for any module I could think of. I the tried things like Z modulo nZ, but couldn't think of modules over them. Naturally, I looked online and I think this is known as the Structure Theorem For PIDs, hence the title, but couldn't find any concrete examples. I've also read that the ideal (x,2) over the integer polynomial ring provides a counter example, i.e. the second part, but I can't see how.

Comment: The rank of the free module is unique.  For examples of modules over the integers it is easy to find ones with torsion because every abelian group is a module over the integers so you can just find an abelian group with torsion.  For example $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$ module.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to ask though, but what is the rank of a free module? I've never seen that term before. I'll see if I can find it in the algebra book. So, when it asks if the free module is unique, it means is the rank unique and the answer is yes?

Comment: All free modules $R$ modules are direct sums of copies of $R$.  The rank of the free module is the cardinality of the number of copies.  For a FGM over a PID the statement is that it is the sum of a free part and a torsion part (where the torsion part has a particularly nice form).  There is a uniqueness statement which tells you that the rank of the free part is unique.

Comment: For examples of free modules where the "rank" is not well defined see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number

Comment: So, over Z, it is saying that the free module is just some (x,y,z,...) such that each entry is an integer where the number of letters is its cardinality?

Comment: I'll have a look at that now!

Comment: rank is basically the cardinality of a basis (think vector spaces).

Comment: I think I understand that. I'm just confused about the uniqueness now as that seems to say you can have separate free modules for a given torsion that give you the same module.

Comment: Do they mean the internal copy of the free part is not unique?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what internal copy means. From the way it's phrased and how they've set up the book, I assumed it meant if given a module and its torsion, then is it possible to find multiple free modules such that added to the torsion give you the first module.

Comment: Ok then they mean the following: the torsion part is cannonical because it is just the set of torsion elements.  But the direct sum complement of the torsion part can be chosen in many ways.  There is not a unique internal direct sum complement.

Comment: So the rank will be well defined but they might not be the same sets viewed in the module.

Comment: Ok, this is where I need to go away and read up on what those mean. If I come back later after reading it, would you still be willing to help?

Comment: I can't guarantee it but I usually check my inbox so probably.  I'm sure others can help too.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help so far! Sorry I'm not that good. :S

Comment: @Zigzag you can alert anyone who has spoken in the thread by using an at sign in front of their name. If you make a comment layer this way, you can draw his ( or my) attention.

Comment: Oh that's quite handy. :D As long as they don't get annoyed when you keep pinging them!

Comment: Ok, so the torsion part has a unique representation but the free module doesn't as you can represent it as a direct sum itself, which the parts being different? Would you be able to give me an example at all? Is this like having 3Z + 5Z and 5Z + 7Z, or something like that?

Comment: I think asking about the uniqueness is getting off path. The example you brought up shows that a module over a domain need not factor into a torsion part and a free part. Wrestling with uniqueness is jumping the gun.

Comment: And nonzero commutative rings, btw, all have IBN, so that is definitely not the problem if we are interested in commutative rings.

Comment: @Seth Just to say thank you for your help. I put a comment below but apparently you might not see it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on the example you gave: view the ideal $I=(x,2)$ inside of the ring $R=\Bbb Z [x]$ as an R module.

Obviously it has no torsion because it's in a domain. That being the case, the entire module would have to be free, in order to fit the decomposition description. We will see this is not possible, so that we have an example of a finitely generated module over a domain which doesn't decompose nicely.

Lets now suppose that it is a free module. (Checking uniqueness of the module or it's rank is premature because we don't even know if it's free yet.)

If $I$ were a direct sum of more than one copy of $R$, then $I$ would contain two nonzero ideals of $R$ that have intersection zero. But this is not possible in a domain! On the other hand, if $I$ were isomorphic to $R$, it would be a cyclic module: but this is also false! Thus $I$ does not decompose into a torsion and free part.

Comment: I'm just going to have a look at what a domain is, but that seems quite intuitive and I understand it in part. So thank you.

Comment: Domain means Integral Domain?

Comment: @zigzag I'll be waiting if you have questions. Yes, I mean integral domain. Let me know if any other breadcrumbs need more explanation, too.

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense. As I said, I'm a biologist and I'm doing it for self-interest so I don't know how precise it needs to be but it satisfies me so thank you. The only other thing I would like to know is what Lang means by unique? Does he mean the rank or does he mean the representation?

Comment: Or does he mean both?

Comment: OH!!!! Something has just clicked regarding the torsion!!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @zigzag the rank. If you look at any vector space of two or more dimensions over a field ( which is a PID, remember!) you will find that complements are not unique.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Homework for the week. :D Thank you very much for your help @Seth and rschwieb (it says you'll be notified anyway and I can only have one at). I now need to go away and read through it so I understand. It's fascinating. :D

Comment: @zigzag another trick: if you comment on an answer, the answerer is automatically notified. I don't think Seth will see the notify since he's not on this thread, but if you do it above he'll see.

Comment: Is there any way to save this question and print it out so I can read it tomorrow in microbiology?

Comment: @zigzag hah, I'm not aware of any special feature for that, but it's a good idea. I would just recommend cut and paste. As for saving, you can click the star under the vote to 'favorite' it, or just access it through your profile where it lists the questions you have asked.